# Report doesn´t show the information Jasper Reports with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jasper-reports, laravel-5

the tink it´s that I´m new with Jasper Reports with Laravel and I don´t know what is happening.... The think it´s that I need to do a query with parameters given by the ReportController of my application... The report it´s already downloading but without data.

There´s my code I have some doubts if the parametrization of my method post  t´s ok

```
public function post()
    {

        $idVersion = session('id_version');
        $database = \Config::get('database.connections.mysql');

        $output = public_path() . '/reportes/'.time().'resumen';
        $ext = "pdf";


        \JasperPHP::process(
            public_path() . '/reportes/resumen.jasper', 
            $output, 
            array($ext),
            array('idVersion' => $idVersion ),
            $database,
            false,
            false
        )->execute();

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.time().'_reportes.'.$ext);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($output.'.'.$ext));
        flush();
        readfile($output.'.'.$ext);
        unlink($output.'.'.$ext); // deletes the temporary file

        return Redirect::to('/reporting');
    }
```

And in the source of my .jrxml report I have:

```
<parameter name="idVersion" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <parameterDescription><![CDATA[idVersion]]></parameterDescription>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM c9.version_resumens WHERE  c9.version_resumens.`ID_VERSION` =  $P{idVersion}]]>
        </queryString>
```

I will be greateful if anyone help me

Comment: Reports are usually empty if no data is available. Try changing when no data to `All sections, no detail`. If you see the empty report, the connection or the SELECT to the DB is wrong. By the way, avoid using `*` in SELECT.

Comment: now I change the report style and get this error.........
Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console.

Comment: Do I have to modify the vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jrxml ???

Comment: Please [edit] your question with: What exactly have you changed where? Of course you need to change this in the designated jrxml which will be compiled to the jasper file.